# Bug in python code preventing successful recursion?

Tags: python

I have been working on a script to ingest a file (accounts.txt) which contains email addresses, for which each will then be verified against an API to see if they appear in a data dump.  The script appears to work, however there is a bug present whereby once it finds a positive hit, it will disregard any other match...

For example;
If my "accounts.txt" file contains the following entries:

```
a@a.com
b@b.com
```

Even though both of those should return results, as soon as the script is run, the match on a@a.com will be found however b@b.com will not return anything.

I cannot seem to figure out why this is happening, ideally I want all of the hits outputted.

FYI, the script is querying 'haveibeenpwned' which is a site that locates email addresses found in credential dumps.

Any help finding my bug would be greatly appreciated.  Below is my current script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse
import json
import requests
import time

breaches_by_date = {}       
breaches_by_account = {}    
breaches_by_name = {}       

class Breach(object):
    def __init__(self, e, n, d):
        self.email = e
        self.name = n
        self.date = d

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s: %s breached on %s" % (self.email, self.name, self.date)

def accCheck(acc):
    global breaches_by_date, breaches_by_account, breaches_by_name
    r = requests.get('https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v2/breachedaccount/%s?truncateResponse=false' % acc)
    try:
        data = json.loads(r.text)
    except ValueError:
        print("No breach information for %s" % acc)
        return
    for i in data:
        name, date = (i['Name'], i['BreachDate'])
        breach = Breach(acc, name, date)
        try: breaches_by_account[acc].append(breach) 
        except: breaches_by_account[acc] = [breach]
        try: breaches_by_name[name].append(breach)
        except: breaches_by_name[name] = [breach]
        try: breaches_by_date[date].append(breach)
        except: breaches_by_date[date] = [breach]

def readFromFile(fname="accounts.txt"):
    accounts=[]
    with open(fname, "r+") as f:
        accounts = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()] 
    return accounts

if __name__ == '__main__':
    accounts = readFromFile()
    for email_addr in accounts:
        accCheck(email_addr)
    print
    print("Breaches by date")
    for date, breaches in breaches_by_date.items():
        for breach in breaches:
            print(breach) 
        print

    print("Breaches by account")
    for acc, breaches in breaches_by_account.items():
        print(acc)
        for breach in breaches:
            print("%s breached on %s" % (breach.name, breach.date)) 
        print

    print("Breaches by name")
    for name, breaches in breaches_by_name.items():
        print("%s breached for the following accounts:" % name)
        for breach in breaches:
            print("%s on %s" % (breach.email, breach.date))
        print
```

Comment: Have your debugging efforts thus far given you any hint as to where the issue may lie? Also consider swapping those global dicts for `defaultdict`. Those try/except blocks are hard on the eye and also can be avoided.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm really not sure.  Thank you for the advice, I will try out defaultdict.

Comment: I would recommend inserting some print statements into the code, if you are not familiar enough with a debugger. These kind of `why doesnt it work` questions normally get closed pretty fast on here. It's good for your progression in learning to get your hands dirty in finding and fixing issues like this yourself. If someone else just shows you, you miss a valuable opportunity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure to know where your problem comes from, but I would opt for a code like:

```
emails_to_check = open("/path/to/yourfile").read().split("\n")
for email in emails_to_check:
 if is_email_blacklisted(email):
  do_something()
```

Comment: Hi Arturo, thank you for your advice, I will try out that code and see if it gives me more reliable results.

Comment: Any progress ? :-)

Comment: Apologies for the belated reply, but after some work your advice helped me get it working.  I was over complicating things I think.  Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! :-D Happy to help